# F# how to run several asynchrous tasks and wait for result of first completed?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

There are many examples how to execute async tasks in f# like

```
[dowork 1; work 2]
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

But how I can asynchronously wait for only the first result?

For example if I want to run some parallel look up tasks and I want to search deeper when the first successful result is obtained. (Basically the equivalent as `Task.WhenAny` in the C# world...)

Comment: Are you expecting the other tasks to be aborted, or just to let them carry on in the background?

Comment: I don't want to abort them, but may be in the future I want to extend this method to something like WaitForAnySuccessfullAndFaiIfAllFail. I am new in f#. In scala world it was pretty simple to implement this with futures and promises.

Comment: It's worth noting that since F# 4.5, this is built in as `Async.Choice`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use something like:

```
let any asyncs =
    async {
        let t = 
            asyncs
            |> Seq.map Async.StartAsTask
            |> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAny
        return t.Result.Result }
```

Comment: Isn't this blocking though? How about piping the result of `WhenAny` into `Async.AwaitTask`, using `let! t` and then returning `t.Result`?

Comment: @nphx: can you add your proposal as a new answer or use gist please?

Answer (score 5):

A general-purpose solution can be found in the following snippet: http://fssnip.net/dN

`Async.Choice` can be embedded in any asynchronous workflow, just like `Async.Parallel`. The optional output type encodes the possibility that a child computation can complete without a satisfactory result.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't something like this included in Async. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @LeafGarland it is now included: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#Choice

Answer (score 3):

The simplest possible implementation I could think of looks something like this:

```
open FSharp.Control

let getOneOrOther () =
    let queue = BlockingQueueAgent(1)
    let async1 = async {
            do! Async.Sleep (System.Random().Next(1000, 2000))
            do! queue.AsyncAdd(1) } |> Async.Start
    let async2 = async {
            do! Async.Sleep (System.Random().Next(1000, 2000))
            do! queue.AsyncAdd(2) } |> Async.Start

    queue.Get()

for i in 1..10 do
    printfn "%d" <| getOneOrOther ()

Console.ReadLine () |> ignore
```

It relies on the blocking queue implementation from the [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/) project, which you will probably want for other reasons. But if you don't want any dependencies `System.Collections.Concurrent` also includes a blocking queue, with a slightly less nice interface.

For a more general version with cancellation built in, the version below takes a `Seq<unit -> Async<'T>>` and returns the first result to come through, cancelling all the others.

```
open FSharp.Control
open System.Threading

let async1 () = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (System.Random().Next(1000, 2000))
        return 1 }
let async2 () = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (System.Random().Next(1000, 2000))
        return 2 }

let getFirst asyncs =
    let queue = BlockingQueueAgent(1)
    let doWork operation = async { 
            let! result = operation()
            do! queue.AsyncAdd(result) }
    let start work =
        let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
        Async.Start(work, cts.Token)
        cts
    let cancellationTokens =
        asyncs
        |> Seq.map doWork
        |> Seq.map start
    let result = queue.Get()
    cancellationTokens
    |> Seq.iter (fun cts -> cts.Cancel(); cts.Dispose())
    result

for i in 1..10 do
    printfn "%A" <| getFirst [async1;async2]

Console.ReadLine () |> ignore
```

Answer (score 3):

Another implementation based on an event:

```
let Choice (asyncs: seq<Async<'T>>) : Async<'T> =
    async {
        let e = Event<'T>()
        let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
        do Async.Start(
            asyncs
            |> Seq.map (fun a -> async { let! x = a in e.Trigger x })
            |> Async.Parallel
            |> Async.Ignore,
            cts.Token)
        let! result = Async.AwaitEvent e.Publish
        cts.Cancel()
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this solution is simple enough, nonblocking and works for my case

```
let any (list: Async<'T>[])=
    let tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<'T>()

    list |> Array.map (fun wf->Async.Start (async{
                let! res=wf
                tcs.TrySetResult (res) |> ignore
            }))
         |> ignore

    Async.AwaitTask tcs.Task

let async1 = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (System.Random().Next(1000, 2000))
        return 1 }
let async2 = async {
        do! Async.Sleep (System.Random().Next(1000, 2000))
        return 2 }

printfn "%d" <| ([|async1;async2|] |> any |> Async.RunSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since F# 4.5, this is built in as `Async.Choice`
https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#Choice